# How to make a USB receiver for the wireless mouse?

Tags: wireless, mouse

I have a Microsoft Wireless mouse but the USB receiver is long lost. Is there anyway I can make the receiver myself?

Comment: Not without having intimate knowledge of Microsoft's wireless protocols and frequencies, and getting anything intimate from Microsoft is impossible. Buy a new mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Not in any practical sense. The mouse and the lost wireless receiver unit may even be a matched pair that pass a digital code to indicate "this is me". Even if you could practically replicate the electronics of the lost item you would still need to cross the hurdle of the wireless protocol and any "this is me" hand shake or validation.

The best course of action is to get a new wireless device. The newest ones have come down significantly in price and even tend to work lot better than older wireless devices.

Comment: Micheal, woudl you happen to know how to actually build a dongle from scratch?

Comment: @George - Give up on the idea. Buy another mouse. Such project is no more practical today than it was five years ago when this question was asked / answered. If you are just missing the wireless receiver you could look online to purchase a replacement. Some like those from Logitech can be had for reasonable price. Logitech has an app you can run on your computer to pair a replacement receiver with the mouse.

Comment: Michael thank you. I would actually like to know what the dongle schematic looks like and how the initial pairing is done. Do you know where to look for such info?

Comment: @George - I have no idea, nor do I have zero incentive to search for such information. What I can tell you, due to the very small size of most modern wireless mouse dongles, is that highly likely that these are comprised of a single custom chip that is devised by each specific manufacturer as a totally proprietary chip. With that in mind think of a single chip that accepts USB V+, D-, D+ and GND on one side and an antenna connection on the other side. Safe to say that is likely the schematic save for the USB connector, a bypass capacitor for the special chip and trace lines to make an antenna.